# Writing wrapper of a third party paid library and trying to hide the .jar file of third party lib from my .aar lib project

Tags: android, jar, aar

I have a .aar library project, which is the wrapper of  third party paid .jar lib. I want to distribute my .aar (wrapper of third party .jar) .

But when I'm trying to use my .aar file in application project, I'm able to see the third party .jar file and its classes very clearly. I want to hide the third party paid .jar file, what i mean is the devleoper who uses my .aar file should not see the .jar(third party file) file.

I tried putting the dependency scope of .jar(third party) as "provided" which is hiding the .jar files but at the same time, the classes of .jar file are missing at the time of running. Causing runtime exception.

My .aar project need the third party .jar lib at the time of compiling and runtime also. But, the developer who uses my .aar file should not see the .jar.

Help me with this. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can repackage the jar library with [jarjar](https://github.com/shevek/jarjar#using-with-gradle) and additionally obfuscate your aar with [proguard](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType:minifyEnabled)

Comment: repackaging the jar library with jarjar is fine. but the problem is in there are native libraries also with the .jar file. So repackaging the .jar causing UnsatisfiedLinkError  with the native libraries at runtime.